# Comparing outputs from 2 separate sql queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query for an inventory system. In order to do this I have to count the number of duplicates in one table and then compare it to the default quantity values taken from another table.

Here are two queries which I am working with currently:

```
SELECT Template_ID, 
COUNT(Template_ID) AS Howmuch, t.name  
FROM consumables e, templates t 
Where t.consumable_type_id = '2410980'
GROUP BY template_id, t.name
HAVING ( COUNT(Template_ID) > 1 )
```

The query above takes account of each unique Template Id and gives me a count of how many duplicates are present which tells me the amount of a single substance.

```
   Select 
      property_descriptors.default_value, 
      templates.name 
   From 
     templates, 
     Property_descriptors 
   Where 
     templates.consumable_type_id = '858190' And 
     templates.audit_id = property_descriptors.audit_id And 
     property_descriptors.name = 'Reorder Point'
```

This query finds the amount of each individual substance we would like to have in our system.

My Issue is that I dont know of a way to compare the results from the 2 queries.

Ideally, I want the query to only give the substance which have a duplicate count lower than their default value (found using query 2).

any ideas would be appreciated!

here is the table schema for reference:

### Consumables

ID|Template_ID|

### Templates

ID|Property_Descriptor_ID|Name|audit_id

### Property_Descriptors

ID| Name|Default_Value|audit_id

Thanks!

Comment: In the first query, are you pulling any values from the `Consumables` table? You're cross-joining the table to `Templates` - is that intentional? Also, where does `Template_ID` come from - `Templates` or `Consumables`?

Comment: Tthe consumable table consists of a bunch of duplicate template_ids. I need to get a count of the number of duplicates in the consumable tables. I am cross joining the template and consumables table in order to get the name each substance as the consumable table does not contain the actual name of the substance.The template_ID orignate from the Templates table.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT  q1.name, q2.default_value - q1.Howmuch  FROM 
        (SELECT Template_ID, COUNT(Template_ID) AS Howmuch, t.name
           FROM consumables e, templates t 
           Where t.consumable_type_id = '2410980'
           GROUP BY template_id, t.name
           HAVING ( COUNT(Template_ID) > 1 )) q1, 
         (SELECT property_descriptors.default_value default_value, 
          templates.name  name
          FROM 
           templates, 
           Property_descriptors 
         WHERE
         templates.consumable_type_id = '858190' And 
         templates.audit_id = property_descriptors.audit_id And 
         property_descriptors.name = 'Reorder Point') q2
         where q1.name = q2.name
```

should do the trick you'll need to clean up the result a bit to work away negative results
or add      `q2.default_value - q1.Howmuch > 0` in the outer WHERE clause

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the query. I have never worked with sql statements nested like that, sort of blew my mind! :p I tried running it however there sql developer keeps telling me there is a syntax error of some sort around line 15... "property_descriptors.name = 'Reorder Point')) q2". It doesnt like the assignment of q2 for that select statement. any ideas?

Comment: only one closing bracket is needed in that place, I think. The corresponding opening bracket is right before the SELECT.

Comment: property_descriptors.name = 'Reorder Point')) q2  remove the last ) There are nicer ways to do it but this is an easy trick for these kind of problems

Comment: Thanks, ok so I ran the query however its giving me erroneous results. Just trying to understand the query... in the orignal response when you wrote q1.consumables = q2.default_value, why did you write q1.consumables because consumables is a table not a column.I think it should be something like q1.count(template_ID)=q2.default_value. Any suggestions on how to write in proper syntax?

Comment: I have updated the query, the where q1.name = q2.name is just a join between q1 and q2, presuming that they are the keys

Comment: ok so the updated query got me very close to what I was looking for. However, in the final output the q1.name does not match the q1.Howmuch values properly. Could this be an issue with last join statement you updated? here is a picture of the output, the Howmuch values are correct however they are not properly matched with the name. https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1hDdsE-gSEmurhhJEOOOlxBcfw9ZCZhogVlqJwGobTLA/pub?w=960&h=720